# RotateTowards not rotating transform.forward

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two objects, predator and prey. I am trying to write code so that when the predator sees the prey, it rotates in its direction and moves forward (in that same direction).

```
Vector3.RotateTowards (transform.forward, preyPos, Mathf.Infinity, Mathf.Infinity);
transform.Translate (transform.forward * predatorSpeed);
```

My understanding is that the above code should rotate transform.forward, however it is the same vector both before and after that line. Why is this happening? I have tried many things, but I can't get this to work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Vector3 in Unity is a `struct` (value type) thus always passed by value.

```
Vector3 v = Vector3.zero;
ChangeValue(v); // Change value of v.x, v.y, v.z
Debug.Log(v); // still (0, 0, 0);
```

That said, `Vector3.RotateTowards()` has to return a Vector3. Basically, you need:

```
transform.forward = Vector3.RotateTowards (transform.forward, preyPos, Mathf.Infinity, Mathf.Infinity);
```

But i'm not sure it will work because `transform.forward` is immutable.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.RotateTowards.html

If you want rotating to face a target, consider 1 of these:

[Transform.LookAt();](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html)
[Quaternion.RotateTowards();](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html)
*Quaternion is a `struct` as well so please read the docs carefully.*

Comment: I had tried that use of RotateTowards, but it doesn't work. Transform.LookAt() ended up being what I needed. Thanks!!